# Find equation of tangent to $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$ curve that is located in maximum distance from origin.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Find equation of tangent to $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$ curve that is   located in maximum distance from origin.

My work:

I tried to transform this into parametric form. $y=(a^{\frac{2}{3}}-x^{\frac{2}{3}})^\frac{3}{2}$ taking $t=x^\frac{2}{3}$, parametric form will be$(t,(a^\frac{2}{3}-t)^\frac{3}{2})$. And then finding derivative of this $(1,-\frac{3}{2}(a^\frac{2}{3}-t)^\frac{1}{2})$. So now I have derivative of our parametric curve. How continue from here?
[image]

I am getting equation of tangent line $y=-xtg(\phi) + a(sin^{3}(\phi)cos(\phi) + cos^{3}\phi sin(\phi))$

from here distance from $(0,0)$ will be $$\frac{a|sin^3(\phi)cos(\phi) + cos^{3}(\phi)sin(\phi)|cos(\phi)||}{|sin(\phi)|}$$ how continue?

Comment: Did you plot original curve? If so good to include a graph and where you think it appears the max distance achieved.

Comment: Can you plot and see what should the required tangent look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "located in maximum distance from the origin"? Do you mean the point of tangency is farthest from the origin or the distance between the tangent line and the origin is maximum or another meaning?

Comment: @BernardMasse distance between tangent line and the origin is the maximum

Comment: Note that this tangent line is not unique, due to the symmetry of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...you can parameterize this curve with $$x=a\cos^3t$$
$$y=a\sin^3t$$

Thus $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\tan t$$ and you can write down the equation of the tangent at the general point $(a\cos^3t,a\sin^3t)$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: equation of tangent line is $(x-a\cos^3(\theta))\sin(\theta)+(y-a\sin^3(\theta))\cos(\theta)=0$ how find maximum distance from origin?

Comment: the equation of the tangent can be greatly simplified, and there is a formula for the perpendicular distance from a point to a line